# How to change an iOS application icon programmatically with image from URL?

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a lot of useful information on how to change the app icon programmatically using "setAlternateIconName" in Swift.
According to the documentation of apple, the name of the alternate icon has to be declared in the CFBundleAlternateIcons key of the app's Info.plist file.

Now, I don't want to use pre-saved jpg./png. images to change the app icon. **Instead, I'd like to download an image from a URL from within the app and us this downloaded image as the app icon**. Obviously, it's not possible to just add the URL to Info.plist in the appropriate field..
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Best,
Nik

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to set the app icon to custom icon other than those set in CFBundleAlternateIcons in Info.plist

Comment: ok but... how we can do that?